# How can I represent a range of floats (x to y) as a set of doubles from a range of 0-1 where x is 0 and y is 1?

Tags: c#, math, formula

As is in the question title, I am looking for an efficient way to represent a set of float values between (and including) values x and y, in a set of doubles from 0-1 where x is equal to 0 and y is equal to 1. Then fill in the values in between.

Let's assume x is 5 and y is 20.

Now, 5 = 0, 20 = 1.
Is there a mathematical function to determine the value of 10 in c#?

I feel like I just can't think of a way to do this programmatically where I can interchange the values of x and y. The values given for x and y will be single digits. Values ranging from 0-1 should have an accuracy of 2 decimal values. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you think of anything more complicated than linear mapping?

Comment: You mean something like `(value - lower) / (upper - lower)`?

Comment: Are you linearly interpolating (like @harold suggests), or using some other function?

Comment: Yes, I am linearly interpolating and will try what @harold suggested. Thank you

Comment: If you cannot do basic mathematic, then programming is not for you.

Comment: @Phil1970 I'm sorry if my math failed me today. I have been working 12 - 14 hour shifts for the past three weeks and am very tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own function which takes x and y with a third parameter being your value you want to map and then return it like:

```
 Static double Map(float x, float y, float inputValue){ Return Convert.ToDouble((inputValue-x)/(y-x));}
```

From a logical standpoint, you are trying to find what fraction the way your InputValue is between x and y. Imagine a long road with someone somewhere in the middle. To find what fraction the way he is along, you must find how far he has travelled, which is his position minus the starting position, then divide that by the total distance of the road, which would be in this case y(the end) -x(the starting position)

Comment: Thank you, you helped me understand how an answer posted in the comments works.